Palabras españolas de origen persa
La pregunta titulada «Looking for info on the history of Spanish» de rosends el 15 de octubre de 2024 fue rechazada por ser demasiado imprecisa.
El tema parecía lo suficientemente interesante para volver a preguntárselo.

¿Es correcto que «matar» derive de la palabra persa «mat»?
¿Hay varias palabras que descienden del persa?
¿De qué manera acabaron en español?
¿Puede dar algunos ejemplos de tales palabras?



Falso, no deriva del persa, deriva del latín mactare, de mactus, que a su vez viene del protoindoeuropeo. Por supuesto, ambas palabras son cognados porque ambas lenguas son protoindoeuropeas y por lo tanto la raíz que dio origen a ambas palabras probablemente es la misma. Pero ambas transitaron caminos completamente distintos. Son cognados, primos hermanos lejanos. No, ni siquiera son cognados. El hecho de que se parezcan es pura casualidad, tras volver a investigar, resulta que la palabra en persa vendría, o del árabe o del protoindoeuropeo *meh₁-; mientras que el camino para mactare termina en *meh₂ḱ-.
No, son muy pocas. No es cómo ocurrió con el árabe que estuvo en contacto directo con el español en gran parte de la historia. La cantidad de palabras que vienen realmente del persa (que surgieron allí) no debe llegar a mil.
La gran mayoría son adaptaciones indirectas conseguidas a través del francés, del inglés, del turco o del árabe, al no haber estado en contacto las poblaciones de ambas tribus. Esto significa que son palabras que también existen de una u otra forma en las demás lenguas romances y en el inglés, a diferencia del repertorio de léxico árabe casi exclusivo que tiene el español en contraste con los demás idiomas.
El motor de búsqueda de Wikcionario permite filtrar palabras por origen, haciendo un poco de uso de la inteligencia, y en donde se verifica todo lo que dije anteriormente.

Como curiosidad, jaque mate, una de las formas de ganar en ajedrez, es una palabra que viene del persa shah mat (el rey ha muerto ha sido sorprendido). De aquí deriva mate, como abreviación del término anterior. Agréguese este término a la lista de cognados de matar. Pero, de acuerdo a 1., nada que ver con matar.

@tac: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Sólo una observación: te refieres en el punto 4 al “ motor de búsqueda de Wikcionario en donde se verifica todo lo que dije anteriormente”. Este texto empieza con la palabra «Incierta» y el enlace correspondiente remite a un texto que afirma lo contrario de lo que citas en el punto 1.

@user37164 No entendí, qué es lo que empeza por 'incierta'?? El enlace son todas las páginas de palabras de orgien persa, en donde se verifica que: 2. son pocas (75 actualmente) y 3. son adaptaciones indirectas. En dónde se afirma lo contrario de lo que cité en el punto 1?

@tac: ¡Hola! En el sitio que mencionas, busca «matar» y haz clic en esta palabra. La primera entrada es: Incierta1. El número 1 se refiere a «Referencias y notas», al final de la página. Si haces clic en el enlace allí, encontrarás 3 hipótesis conocidas del origen de matar.
En https://cvc.cervantes.es/literatura/aih/pdf/14/aih_14_1_025.pdf, entre otros, se puede leer que, hasta la fecha, no hay ninguna explicación válida para la génesis de la palabra matar.

@user37164 YA veo. Así que también la otra versión del español reconoce a ‘mat’ entre las posibilidades. De todas formas, sigo convencido de que no es así, las palabras que vinieron del árabe son terminología específica para nombres de objetos; pero las acciones básicas y generales que se pueden hacer, es decir el ‘núcleo duro’ del español, vienen todas del latín vulgar. Segundo, en todo caso si sostenés la hipótesis de que viene de ‘mat’, en tal caso vendría del árabe y no del persa, y simplemente sería un cognado adaptado por ambos idiomas desde el árabe.

@tac: El motivo de mi pregunta fue un artículo en el que un etimólogo se mostraba descontento por el hecho de que el último DLE había incluido tu respuesta (1), aunque no hubiera sido así en las versiones anteriores. Esto porque “aún no se han aportado pruebas de ello” (2). Una dificultad se hallaría en que “matar” no se utiliza (salvo en español y portugués) en ninguna otra lengua románica. Tú optas por (1), yo opto por (2), eso está bien. Mejor dejaremos que se peleen entre ellos. Gracias por tu aportación.
